# Warning when rvalue-declared variable goes out of scope being not moved from

Tags: c++, c++11, warnings, move-semantics

Is there a way to make a compiler (*clang++* or *g++*) to inform one about next situations:

```
static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference< T >::value);
void g(T);
void f(T x)
{
    T y = x;
#if 0 // turns warning off
    g(std::move(x));
#endif
} // warning here: x goes out of scope, but not moved from
```

or

```
static_assert(!std::is_reference< T >::value);
T f()
{
    T x;
    T y = x;
#if 0 // turns warning off
    return x;
#else
    return {};
#endif
} // warning here: x goes out of scope, but not moved from
```

Another class of warnings should be triggered, when *moved from* variable used once again:

```
void f()
{
    T x;
    T y = std::move(x);
    T z = x; // warning here: x is used since it has been moved from
}
```

Variables of such non-copyable classes as `std::unique_ptr` are rarely reused after their content has been stealed.

It would be great, if warnings described above would be available as per-variable triggered via `#pragma` or attribute or globally for all variables which types are classes with custom move-assignment operator and constructor.

Sometimes it is hard to follow the lifetime of variable.

There is SSA-form (static single assignment form) of intermediate representation (like AST) used in modern compilers. So I think it is not too hard for compilers to detect above situations.

Comment: "when moved from variable used once again", surely if your moving the contents, you should assume the variable to be in a undefined state - even if it's just an integer, you *shouldn't be using it again*. And if you need to use it, why are you moving it to start with?

Comment: @JohnBargman, no, that's not what moving does. For an integer it will be unchanged, for a `unique_ptr` it has an entirely defined state (it's empty), and for most other types it's "valid but unspecified".

Comment: @Orient, what do you mean "T is a prvalue"? T is a type, not an expression, so that doesn't make sense. For what conditions do you want the warning to trigger?

Comment: @JonathanWakely for complex types (such as classes) that unspecified state is... a bad code smell, as for simple types I'm not certain as to if that validity is implementation defined or part of the standard, do you know? Either way, surely it's bad practice nonetheless?

Comment: @JohnBargman, it's part of the standard, that's why I said it. In any case, aren't you agreeing with the OP, that a warning about using a moved-from variable would be useful?

Comment: @JonathanWakely I mean here, that `T` is `U` but not `U &&` or something else with respect to references. Anyways it not matters much here. Can be removed for clarity.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Yes I am agreeing with the OP in that regard, I was just querying the situation itself. Though thank you for the update regarding move with simple-types.

Comment: @Orient, seems like your warning would trigger for pretty much any function that takes arguments by value or uses local variables ... that's not very useful.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Surely this warning should not be program-wide enabled. Just for (some parts) of user code. Say, it is nonsense to enable it for trivially copyable types.

Comment: You can implement it as static tools (using libclang may help.)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this with GCC or Clang today.

The new `[[nodiscard]]` attribute coming to C++17 is vaguely related, but not the same and can't be used for any of your cases.